# Fire action when WebView loads page

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a `List<Website>` called history, which contains `Website`s, simple wrappers for String-String-Uri groups.
Now, that list is meant to be some sort of "history" for the webview in the activity.
The problem is, it doesn't work.
What I'm doing now is:

Website:

```
public class Webpage implements Serializable {
protected String url;
protected String title;
protected Uri uri;

public Webpage(String title, String url) {
    // ...
}

// Getters and other methods

public JSONObject toJSONObject() throws JSONException {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("title", this.title);
    jsonObject.put("url", this.url);
    return jsonObject;
}

public String serialize(int indentationLevel) {
    try {
        return toJSONObject().toString(indentationLevel);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public String serialize() {
    return serialize(4);
}

public static Webpage deSerialize(JSONObject object) throws JSONException {
    return new Webpage(((String)object.get("title")), ((String)object.get("url")));
}

public static Webpage deSerialize(String jsonObject) throws JSONException {
    return deSerialize(new JSONObject(jsonObject));
}
}
```

WebViewClient:

```
        // ...
        @Override public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String urlStr) {


            OpenTabsActivity.history
                    .ensureCapacity(OpenTabsActivity.history.size+2)
            OpenTabsActivity.history.add(new Webpage(webView.title, urlStr));
            check();
            setTitle(webView.title);
            loadingBar.setProgress(0);
            loadingBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            super.onPageFinished(view, urlStr);
        }
```

Comment: Show off the content of method `ensureCapacity` and `add` that are called right after onPageFinished is called.

Comment: @jantursky I've updated the code above

Comment: Hmmm, you don't get me, I thought this methods `OpenTabsActivity.history.ensureCapacity(OpenTabsActivity.history.size+2)` and `OpenTabsActivity.history.add(new Webpage(webView.title, urlStr));`. Many thanks

Comment: @jantursky doesn't work still... :/

Comment: I wrote you something else. I asked you to share the method content of this two methods `OpenTabsActivity.history.ensureCapacity` and `OpenTabsActivity.history.add`.

Comment: oh, sorry, didn't understand . `OpenTabsActivity.history` is an `ArrayList<Website>`